# Problemas al instalar electron

Tags: linux, npm, electron, instalacion

Obtengo los siguientes errores al instalar electron:

```
sh: 1: node: not found
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron" "--unsafe-perm=true" "--allow-root"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! electron@1.7.12 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.7.12 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs electron
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/    /Escritorio/  -RAT/  /npm-debug.log
root@    -laptop:/home/    /Escritorio/  -RAT/  # npm uninstall -g electron
root@    -laptop:/home/    /Escritorio/  -RAT/  # sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
loadDep:uuid → mapToRegis ▄ ╢██████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine hawk@6.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.5.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","np/usr/local/bin/electron -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

> electron@1.7.12 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron" "--unsafe-perm=true" "--allow-root"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! electron@1.7.12 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.7.12 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs electron
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Escritorio/  -RAT/  /npm-debug.log
```

¿Cómo puedo instalar electron correctamente?

Comment: Te dice que la versión instalada de node es inferior a la que necesita. Tienes 4.2.6 y necesita 4.5.0 o superior, eso como warning y el error viene dado porque no encuentra node instalado en el sistema. ¿Lo tienes en el path?

Comment: puede que en tu `/usr/bin` tengas `nodejs` en vez de node (pasaba en distros antiguas por una colisión de nombres con otro paquete). Si no existe `node` en `/usr/bin` prueba haciendo un link simbólico con `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

En Ubuntu/Debian hay conflicto con el comando "node" [1]

Parecido a la respuesta de @amenadiel arriba, lo solucione creando este symlink con la diferencia que la ruta es  "sbin" en vez de "bin"

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
```

o alternativamente, haciendo:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

que restaura el symlink  /usr/bin/node a /usr/bin/nodejs

[1] en Ubuntu "node" es un symlink a https://www.mankier.com/8/ax25-node

Comment: Tenes experiencia en la red, asi que solo te recomendaria leer el [tour] (ya que todos funcionamos diferente) y tambien mirar [answer]. Se pide que las respuesta sean completas y expliquen la solucion. Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja cailidad.

Comment: @gbianchi edité la respuesta, espero que ahora esté mejor